# Thread cant't see ConcurentHashMap's elements populated by other thread in android 2.3.(5-7)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-1.1

I have Map:

```
public Map  bitmaps = new ConcurrentHashMap  ();
```

One thread for decoding resources which populates bitmaps by:

```
bitmaps.put (resource, BitmapFactory.decodeStream (input, null, options));
```

And second native thread which binds decoded resources to opengl textures:

```
    public void onDrawFrame (GL10 gl)
    {
        if (bitmaps.size()>0)
        {
```

So first thread decodes and second thread binds. This pattern is working fine on android 2.3.3, 2.3.4 and on 4.x.x .

But when it comes to android 2.3.5 or 2.3.6 **the second thread (which must work with first thread's populated bitmaps) in bitmaps.size() always returns 0 while first thread (which populated bitmaps) in the same time returns number more than 0 by calling bitmaps.size().**

So why can't one thread see other thread's populated elements in this versions of android os ?

Comment: Did you see this behaviour in non-opengl context, too? I mean have you tried building a little Test-App with 2 Threads and a ConcurrentHashMap with just some random data and it was the same behaviour? What did "the Android people" say?